# cstdio and cstddef conflict on std::size_t

Tags: c++, size-t, cstdio

test.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>
using std::size_t;
```

To compile:

```
 >  g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o     
In file included from /.../include/stdio.h:75:0,
                 from /.../gcc/include/c++/cstdio:42,
                 from test.cpp:1:
test.cpp:3:12: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
 using std::size_t;
            ^
test.cpp:3:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
test.cpp:3:12: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
```

If I only remove `#include <cstdio>`, everything works fine.
But If I only remove `#include <cstddef>`, the same error pops up.
If I remove both:

```
 >  g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o    
test.cpp:1:12: error: ‘std::size_t’ has not been declared
 using std::size_t;
            ^
```

I need both libraries to be included, as well as `std::size_t` to be used.
What should I in this situation? Should I add some `CXXFLAGS`?

My gcc version is 4.8.5.

```
 >  g++ --version 
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

UPDATE:

I have tried system's default gcc: `/usr/bin/g++`, the error is gone.
So it should be anaconda's gcc to blame. I will raise an issue to the group.
Thank you all.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your case. [Example here](https://godbolt.org/g/uZCKvi). It compiles fine on GCC 4.8.5

Comment: @BiagioFesta It's really weird to me. It didn't make any sense, but it happened. By the way, the gcc is installed from anaconda, do you think does that have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on GCC 7.2 and Clang 5.0.

Comment: @PanwenWang are you sure about `g++ --version`?

Comment: I would suspect the `using` is at fault. Have you tried `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @BiagioFesta See my updates for `g++ --version`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, I tried, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @PanwenWang I'd check the `cstdio` header, maybe there is some miss-alignment with the stdlib. Anyway it's not a *language* problem, but your environment settings

Comment: Your first error message looks like someone did `#define size_t int` in `stdio.h` somewhere.

Comment: Your compiler installation is bugged

Comment: @M.M Yes, you are right. I guess @Biagio Festa and @melpomene are also right, the `stdio.h` file is modified by the conda group.